# Converting unicode characters (C#) Testing

Tags: c#, unicode, replace

I have the following problem

I am using an SDK that returns values form a database.

The value i need is 4, 6, 7 but the SDK returns "\u0004","\u0006","\u0007" I was wondering if there is a way to check if it is "\u0004","\u0006","\u0007" or any way of doing this?

I Have the following code (C#):

```
Line_Type = Line_Type.Replace(@"\u000", "");
if (Line_Type == "4")
{
    Line_Type = "4";
}
else if (Line_Type == "6")
{
    Line_Type = "6";
}
else if (Line_Type == "7")
{
    Line_Type = "7";
}
```

I have tried multiple ways to get the done but can't find a right way to get this done.

I Have google but can't find anything.

Comment: not sure I understand your question, but your code seems to have a few problems: the code within ifs is pointless: `if variable == something variable = something`.  also, you are stripping "\u000" from every value of Line_Type, which maybe is not what you want to do

Comment: yes sorry i have an error in the copying and pasting. In short what i want is to strip \u000 from the Line_Type so that i can only get 4, 6, 7 as a string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your question I understood that SDK returns values in unicoded style.
Then you can use the following code to convert unicode values to respective decimal value.

```
char uniCodeValue = char.Parse(Line_Type);//  '\u0004' unicode values
int decimalValue = uniCodeValue;
Console.Write(decimalValue.ToString()); // prints 4
```

Hope your problem got solved!!

Comment: This code works but i hade to change it a bit thank you verymuch

Comment: Welcome Andre. Please customize the code as your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

In your replace call, "\u" is considered as an escape char. if you use double \, you get the string "\u0009";
check the difference between these two:

```
Console.WriteLine ("\u0009");
Console.WriteLine ("\\u0009");
```

the second print the string you are trying to replace with an empty string.

Comment: Sr as this problem is already solved, but ur error mentioned was wrong. The author type an @ sign before the string which means that \ sign is no longer considered as a Escape Sign.

Comment: right, I missed it. I just upvoted Nikson answer, that actually is the solution for you problem