# Remove unwanted unicode characters from string

Tags: c#

I have looked at quite a number of related SO posts pertaining to this. I have this malformed string that contains unicode characters which I want to strip away.

```
string testString = "\0\u0001\0\0\0����\u0001\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\u0011\u0001\0\0\0\u0004\0\0\0\u0006\u0002\0\0\0\u0005The\u0006\u0003\0\0\0\u0017boy\u0006\u0004\0\0\0\tKicked\u0006\u0005\0\0\0\u0013the Ball\v";
```

I would like the following output:

```
The boy kicked the Ball
```

How can I achieve this?

I have looked at the below (With not much success):

1. [How can you strip non-ASCII characters from a string? (in C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123336/how-can-you-strip-non-ascii-characters-from-a-string-in-c)
2. [Converting unicode characters (C#) Testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33866445/converting-unicode-characters-c-testing)
3. [How to Remove '\0' from a string in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387733/how-to-remove-0-from-a-string-in-c)
4. [Removing unwanted character from column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4991284/removing-unwanted-character-from-column) (SQL Server related so not relevant in my question)

Comment: What's the actual source of `testString`? I assume it's not hard-coded like that in your real code.

Comment: @Enigmativity I got this as a result of doing decryption on an encrypted byte[] array via RSA asymmetric encryption i.e string `testString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(encryptedByteArray, 0, encryptedByteArray.Length);` gave me what I posted in the question. I only just changed the actual strings

Comment: Then I suspect that you need to get your decryption character encoding right. I don't think this is an issue of stripping the Unicode characters. You're doing two wrongs, which isn't a right. Can you please post you decrypted byte array? Then we can probably get your string cleanly without the need to strip anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`testString = Regex.Replace(testString, @"[\u0000-\u0008\u000A-\u001F\u0100-\uFFFF]", "");`

or

`testString = Regex.Replace(testString, @"[^\t\r\n -~]", "");`

Comment: Are you getting the correct output? I'm not winning on my side. I'm getting a "\t"

Comment: Yeah, for both options.   I added a second option.

Comment: The second solution is almost there. Just need some spacing between the words

Answer (score 3):

```
public string ReturnCleanASCII(string s)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s.Length);
        foreach (char c in s)
        {
            if ((int)c > 127) // you probably don't want 127 either
                continue;
            if ((int)c < 32)  // I bet you don't want control characters 
                continue;
            if (c == '%')
                continue;
            if (c == '?')
                continue;
            sb.Append(c);
        }

        
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this regular expression to filter out bad characters in a filename.

```
Regex.Replace(directory, "[^a-zA-Z0-9\\:_\- ]", "")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string s = "søme string";
s = Regex.Replace(s, @"[^\u0000-\u007F]+", string.Empty);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Why not instead of trying to remove the unicode chars, you just extract all ASCII chars:

```
var str = string.Join(" ",new Regex("[ -~]+").Matches(testString).Select(m=>m.Value));
```